# Javascript circular calculation involving arrays (example: amortization schedule)

Tags: javascript, arrays, spreadsheet, lazy-evaluation, circular-reference

I'm fairly early on in building an app that can be used as an alternative to spreadsheets in a number of scenarios. It offers the user a non-tabular approach to creating and organizing the analysis. The user's instructions are transpiled to and executed by Javascript (using pure functions only). (The interface is between something like [Google Blockly](https://developers.google.com/blockly/) and straight coding in a text editor.) In place of cell ranges that you would typically use in a spreadsheet, this product uses Javascript arrays. A problem that I'm facing with this approach is (quasi-)circular calculations such as that found in a simple amortization schedule.

My (unsuccessful) attempts to resolve the issue so far involve:

- lazy list evaluation (using https://github.com/dankogai/js-list-lazy)
- wrapping all transpiled JS in functions to delay eval so that the user's content doesn't need to be topologically sorted (which it currently is).

Below I'll provide hopefully enough context to illustrate the issue, which can be pretty broadly extrapolated. Take the example of an amortization schedule for a mortgage:

Basically, the BOP ("Beginning of Period") Balance depends on the EOP ("End of Period") Balance from the previous period. And the EOP Balance depends on the BOP Balance from the same period. In a spreadsheet that uses ranges of contiguous cells, this isn't circular because every BOP Balance and EOP Balance is a discrete cell. However, if BOP Balance and EOP Balance (and all of the other time-series-based calcs) are arrays then there is a circular reference when trying to retrieve elements. Spreadsheet screenshots of the example are provided at the end of the post as a supplement.

An attempt to build this analysis in my app generates the following JS (which I've edited and reorganized for clarity). This code, if translated over to a spreadsheet, works just fine (see supplemental screenshots at the end of the post):

```
// Credit: Apache OpenOffice
function payment (rate, periods, present_value, future_value, type) {
  var fv = future_value || 0
  var t = type || 0
  if (rate === 0) {
    return -1 * ((present_value + fv) / periods)
  } else {
    var term = (1 + rate) ** periods // Transpiling with Babel; otherwise, use Math.pow(1 + rate, periods)
    if (t === 1) {
      return -1 * ((fv * rate / (term - 1) + present_value * rate / (1 - 1 / term)) / (1 + rate))
    } else {
      return -1 * (fv * rate / (term - 1) + present_value * rate / (1 - 1 / term))
    }
  }
}

var loan_principal = 1000000
var annual_interest_rate = 0.06
var interest_rate_monthly = annual_interest_rate / 12
var amortization_period_years = 25
var amortization_period_months = amortization_period_years * 12

var months_range = _.range(1, amortization_period_months + 1, 1) // See: http://underscorejs.org/#range [1, 2, 3, ... 298, 299, 300]

var bop_balance = months_range.map(function (current_element, current_list_position) {
  if (current_list_position === 0) {
    return loan_principal
  } else {
    // Along with eop_balance, this causes a graph cycle
    return eop_balance[current_list_position - 1]
  }
})

var monthly_payment = months_range.map(function (current_element, current_list_position) {
  return payment(interest_rate_monthly, amortization_period_months, loan_principal)
})

var principal_payment = months_range.map(function (current_element, current_list_position) {
  var current_mthly_pmt = monthly_payment[current_list_position]
  var current_int_pmt = interest_payment[current_list_position]
  return current_mthly_pmt - current_int_pmt
})

var interest_payment = months_range.map(function (current_element, current_list_position) {
  if (current_list_position === 0) {
    return loan_principal * interest_rate_monthly * -1
  } else {
    var previous_bal = eop_balance[current_list_position - 1]
    return previous_bal * interest_rate_monthly * -1
  }
})

var eop_balance = months_range.map(function (current_element, current_list_position) {
  // This causes a graph cycle
  var cur_bal = bop_balance[current_list_position]
  var cur_prin_pmt = principal_payment[current_list_position]
  return cur_bal + cur_prin_pmt
})
```

This code will not topologically sort because of the cycle between bop_balance and eop_balance. And it won't fully evaluate because of the circular reference.

Any suggestions on how to work around this general scenario? Thank you.

Supplemental Info:

Here are two views of the same spreadsheet representing the analysis:
[image: Amortization schedule showing values]
[image: Amortization schedule showing formulas]

The reliance on pure functions in the app is to try and minimize confusion for users coming from spreadsheets.

If seeing the actual app would help provide context, please feel free to visit https://www.getpinevale.com. I'm placing this at the end so it doesn't distract from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't do a double linked structure. I would suggest use a plain for loop and build up both arrays.

```
for(int i=0; i<range.length;i++){
  if(i==0){
    bop_balance[i]= loan_principal;
    eop_balance[i]= somecalculatedamount(loan_principal);
  }else{
    bop_balance[i] = eop_balance[i-1];
    eop_balance[i] = somecalculatedamount(bop_balance[i])
  }
}
```

I don't know if my function is correct but the essential point I am trying to make:

- don't link the data structures
- and use a control structure that is outside of both arrays

---

Based on the comment below I'd make the suggestion of using reduce.

```
let range = [1,2,3,4];
let output = range.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex) {
  let balance = {};
  if (currentIndex == 0) {
    balance.bop = 0;
    balance.eop = currentValue;
  }else{
    balance.bop = accumulator[currentIndex-1].eop;
    balance.eop = balance.bop+5;
  }

  accumulator.push(balance);
  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. What I should have been explicit about (and will add to the question now) is that the app only uses pure functions. This is largely to try and limit confusion for the user that is coming from spreadsheets. For example, if you set the value of some spreadsheet cell to 10, you can't write a formula somewhere else that changes the value _of that same cell_ to a different number. Your suggestion appears to be a way to solve the problem by mutating the arrays (please correct me if I am wrong!). Does that make sense? Thanks again.

Comment: Based on what you say about wanting to be pure functional programming I'd suggest using reduce: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce - i've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks again, Gratus. This approach definitely works. I'll have to reflect a bit on how to represent the pattern in the app's UI such that it isn't too difficult for a non-programmer. My hope was that there would be a way to achieve the goal using the map pattern (perhaps with lazy evaluation), which is a bit simpler in that all the "columns" of data can be kept separate.